# How to access data of child widget in parent in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, inherited-widget

I want to know the value of a certain field in a child (or child of child) widget in the parent widget, only when I want to know it.
Using a **Callback** or **InheritedWidget/Provider** doesn't work in this case as it provides me information every time there's a change in the value in the child. I only require the child's value, when there's an action in the parent. So, listening to all the changes is an overhead.
Another option is using a **key** to fetch the information from the child, but the children can be multiple, so will have to create those many keys and somehow attaching them to the children. And keys are a bit expensive.
Another option would be to store instances of the children and getting value from it.

Every option seems like overkill for a simple task. I am favoring on the key approach as it gives a feeling that they were created for these types of scenarios. Does anyone know anything better for this situation?

A simple use case is:
Imagine a parent having a PageView in the middle and a next button. The page in the middle contains a slider which changes its value. When we press next, we wanna know what's the slider's final value is.

Comment: You can use static on one of the variable inside your child widget to directly access a value. I don't understand why provider/callback doesn't work though. I am using a scopedModel plugin (similar to provider) on my children and I can get whatever information i update inside my children widget.

Comment: you can read the post I wrote : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Comment: @FadhliS making variables static means, everyone will have access to them. Which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, @diegoveloper, I did. And it's quite a helpful post. Although the question's use case is a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason why it seems so hard: you shouldn't.

Widgets are purposefully very limited to enforce an uni-directional data-flow, which is critical for maintainability of larger apps.

Instead of reading the state of your descendants, you should "lift the state up" through inherited-widgets and similar patterns.

Comment: "Widgets are purposefully very limited to enforce an uni-directional data-flow, which is critical for maintainability of larger apps". Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: can you add a reference to this pattern for Flutter?